# Cell address defined by the contents of other cells

Tags: excel

How do you define variable cell address in Excel.  For example consider the case where the content of cell A1 is 5, cell A2 is 2, cell A3 is 10 and cell A4 is 1.  How do I enter a general formula to SUM the content of the cells A7 (A1+A2) through A9 (A3-A4)?  I would then like to drag the formula to columns B through CJ,... and repeat similar calculations noting that values of B1 through CJ4 are different than A1 through A4.  I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,A1+A2,1):INDEX(A:A,A3-A4))
```